# SQL Exception is not being caught as a SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I am trying to add some retry ability to a persistent application that I have observed crashes randomly due to the SQL Connection being closed remotely. I can't debug why it gets closed, but I can discern it is transient and resumes right away. So naturally I wrote this guarded code:

```
try 
{
    //do stuff that sometimes requires use of SQL
} 
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlEx) 
{
    if (myConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) 
    {
        try 
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex2)  
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not reconnect", ex2);
        }
    } 
    else 
        throw new Exception("Unhandled SQL exception", sqlEx);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    throw new Exception("Unhandled exception", ex);
}
```

And then I put a breakpoint in the `do stuff` block, and manually closed the connection to test the error handling.

But it skips directly to the generic Exception catch block at the end, completely bypassing the retry catch on `SqlException`.

What am I doing wrong to catch SQL exceptions?

<sub>I realize that if the expected `catch` block were invoked, more analysis of the `slqEx` variable would be appropriate.</sub>

Comment: Did you check what's the actual exception being thrown when you forcibly close the connection?

Comment: Whoops, it's an `InvalidOperationException`. I assumed an error doing anything SQL related would throw a `SqlException` (it isn't even an inner exception).

Comment: Maybe you can use the message or something to determine that's actually a `SqlException`? If you can post the actual error, we may be able to help narrow down the scope

Comment: If the message is distinct enough, you can catch the InvalidOperationException along with an exception filter `catch(InvalidOperationException ioe) when (ioe.Message == "some message" ) {...} ` this way you only catch the actual exception you need. I've falling into this before, assuming that all sql ops threw SqlExceptions-- also untrue for Zombied Transactions which *also* throw InvalidOperationException :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Sql connector determines that your connection is not open so it complains about it before event attempting to talk to Sql server.

Thus you are getting an `InvalidOperationException` instead of `SqlException` because the exception was not throw by Sql server. In fact Sql server was not involved at all.

[image]

This is different than a connection being closed remotely, which will [act differently](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/).

Comment: This is the same answer I already responded with. Please supply your contribution appropriately via an edit and I will include it. Thank you.

Comment: @Elaskanator what do you mean by my contribution? I provided the reasoning of why you are seeing one exception instead of the other. If its not thrown by Sql then it might not be a Sql exception. remotely closed connection is closed by sql and thrown by Sql thus its different than manual close.